# How do the aiming options work when in a vehicle in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When in a vehicle, there are two aiming options - aim, and aim + fire. From testing, it seems like when "aim + fire" is chosen, holding down R1 on my PS4 controller automatically shoots - whereas when just "aim" is selected, both R1 and L1 must be used to shoot.

When "aim + fire" is selected, does holding down R1 automatically aim and fire at the closest target? When using "aim" only, when R1 is held do you then have the option of aiming - and if so, how can this be done? I'm totally blind, so haven't had chance to test this with somebody sighted.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no autoaim while driving.

**Aim and fire:**
no autoaim

- R2 is drive
- L1 is weapon aim (white dot)
- right stick steers weapon
- R1 shoots weapon
- left stick steers car

**Just Fire** (same as PS3):no autoaim.

L1 is both aim and shoot.